# How to use custom google fonts classes in vue-vuetify project?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am using **Inter** font in my vue-vuetify project. I wanted to know that is there any way through which I can use the Inter font classes in my project directly?

Thin, Extra-light, light, medium, etc. are the classes available in Inter font. How to use these classes in my project directly?

Please refer this link for more

> https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter?selection.family=Inter:wght@100

How can I apply any class for example **Thin** in my project?

Currently, I am doing this by declaring CSS in my project and setting the **font-weight** property as per each and every class.
But, it isn't the same as these classes.

For example, I have declared a css class namely

```
.headline-5 {
    letter-spacing: 0.46px;
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Which has the same class as of Inter Regular. Is this approach correct or any other way is possible?

Comment: You mean you need to display `headline-5` as the same font as `Inter Thin`?

Comment: Umm. I hade made a minor change in my question. Please have a look at it now.
Basically I want to use Inter Thin, so I wanted to ask that I need to declare headline-5 in my css or is there any way through which I can direclty use Inter Thin?

Comment: `Is this the right approach`? -- I'd say, yes. Another way would be to set the attributes via [`element.style.fontWeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight#JavaScript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which has the same class as of Inter Regular. Is this approach correct or any other way is possible?

I think a good approch would be to create a base class for `Inter Regular` like:

```
.headline-5 {
    letter-spacing: 0.46px;
    color: #000000;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 23px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

and a thin class modifier for it, just to update the `font-weight` like:

```
.headline-5.thin {
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

Then you can use `Regular` and `Thin` font versions in any place you like:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;400&display=swap');
.container {
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}

.headline-5 {
  letter-spacing: 0.46px;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.headline-5.thin {
  font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="headline-5 thin">Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
  <p class="headline-5">Almost before we knew it, we had left the ground.</p>
</div>
```